# fading background does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css

This is my attempt to make a menu with a fading background when the mouse hovers over the menu item.  It works in Firefox (10.0.2), but it does not work in Chrome (17.0.963.79).  I was under the impression this would work using Chrome version 17.  What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
div.Menu{
    border: solid black 4px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.MenuItem{
    border: solid black 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    transition: background-color 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms ease-out;
}

div.MenuItem:hover{
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Menu">
        <a href=""><div class="MenuItem"></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="MenuItem"></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="MenuItem"></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="MenuItem"></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="MenuItem"></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="MenuItem"></div></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported problem with Chrome 16 and 17. If you set the `<a href="#">` then it works fine, it's a problem with the :visited tag in Chrome. It is noted on chromium.

`After some experimentation, it seems to have something to do with <a href> being "visited". Non-visited links fade properly, and I think divs work fine too.`

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103354#c12)

For example, if you check out the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/joshuamartin/hRAu4/1/ you'll see it works fine.

e: It has been fixed in the v18 beta, so it shouldn't be an issue around for much longer!

Comment: Thank you.  I should have posted this yesterday instead of tearing my hair out trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: No worries. It's always the way isn't it? You spend so long working out something, only to realise there's nothing you can do about it!